# How to access "this" inside a parametic function on addevent listener

Tags: javascript, dom

I have been trying to access the `cloneN.querySelector('.defaultDBIcon')` element(div element) inside a function `makeD`. I want to send two parameters for the function. Any idea how should I access this function?

```
cloneN.querySelector('.def').addEventListener("click",makeD(response,this));
```

Comment: `cloneN.querySelector('.def').addEventListener("click",makeD);`, you have `this` as `element` on which `click-event` is attached!

Comment: @Rayon—and the other parameter?

Comment: @RobG, I guess it is global so could be accessed in any function..

Comment: @Rayon - the other parameter is not gobal, that is was the issue in the first place...

Comment: @kamalpluto, `cloneN.querySelector('.def').addEventListener("click",makeD.bind(cloneN.querySelector('.def'), response));`

Comment: Is `this` supposed to be the element they clicked on, or the value of `this` in the function that contains this code?

Comment: @Barmar "this" is the element that will be clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a function, it will receive the event target as its context when it's called.

```
cloneN.querySelector('.def').addEventListener("click", function() {
    return makeD(response, this);
});
```